# Relationship between current, voltage, magnetic field in a torus

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

I'm trying to find the relation between current density $\boldsymbol{j}$, voltage $v$, and magnetic field $\boldsymbol{B}$ for the time-harmonic approximation in a cylindrically-symmetric coil (a torus if you will) onto which a current is applied. The coordinates are $r$, $z$, $\theta$.

What I got so far is:

- The current density can be written as
  $$
  \boldsymbol{j} = \exp(\text{i}\omega t) j \boldsymbol{e}_{\theta}
  $$
  with a scalar function $j$.
- The magnetic vector potential $\boldsymbol{A}$ if the magnetic field $\boldsymbol{B}$($=\nabla\times \boldsymbol{A}$) has the form
  $$
  \boldsymbol{A} = \exp(\text{i}\omega t) \phi \boldsymbol{e}_{\theta}
  $$
  with a scalar function $\phi$ (and the angular frequency $\omega$); $\boldsymbol{e}_\theta$ is the unit vector in direction $\theta$.

From Maxwell's equations, it follows that
$$
\nabla\times \boldsymbol{E} + \text{i}\omega \boldsymbol{B} = \boldsymbol{0},
$$
so
$$
\nabla\times (\boldsymbol{E} + \text{i}\omega \boldsymbol{A}) = \boldsymbol{0}.
$$
With Ohm's law, $\boldsymbol{j} = \sigma \boldsymbol{E}$, and the above representations, we have
$$
\nabla\times ((\sigma^{-1} j + \text{i}\omega \phi)\boldsymbol{e}_{\theta}) = \boldsymbol{0}.
$$
This means that the quantity $r(\sigma^{-1} j + \text{i}\omega \phi)$ must be a constant in the coil. I suspect that it takes a value that depends on the applied voltage $v$, but I fail to see how that would come in.